# Keep selected items from list box after redrawing box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have a dev express (MVVM) check box - list box edit (with Caliburn Micro) that allows for multiple select that I am attempting to attach a search function to, it is working as expected, however when I have items selected, then search, the previously selected items are lost. heres my XAML:

```
<layout:LayoutItem Label="label : " Foreground="White" LabelPosition="Top">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SeachItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="400">
                </TextBox>

                <dxe:ListBoxEdit DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Foreground="Black" Margin="10" Width="400" DisplayMember="Name" MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" EditValue="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                    <dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                        <dxe:CheckedListBoxEditStyleSettings />
                    </dxe:ListBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
            </DockPanel>
        </layout:LayoutItem>
```

The declarations for the list box (I think this may be part of my issue, as I can not figure out a way to bind my selections to an `ObservableCollection`, I can only seemt to bind them to a generic list):

```
public ObservableCollection<Items> Items { get; set; }
public List<object> SelectedItems { get; set; }
```

And here is my search method:

```
private string _searchItems;
public string SeachItems
    {
        get { return _searchItems; }
        set
        {
            _searchItems = value;
            var tempItems = SelectedItems;
            var items = //fetch all items from collection;
            Items = (from p in items where p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SeachItems.ToLower()) orderby p.Name select p).ToObservableCollection();

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Items);
            SelectedItems = tempItems;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>SelectedItems);

        }
    }
```

Although `SelectedItems` does have a count upon calling the `NotifyOfPropertyChange()`, upon viewing the actual listbox no items are checked, and the next search clears out the `SelectedItems` any pointers?

Edit:

In the Setup Model I am populating `Items` and creating am instance of `SelectedItems`

```
Items = //populate observable collection from database
SelectedItems = new List<object>();
```

Comment: You should use a view to do the filtering, rather than actually replacing the collection of items. It's also not clear where your declared `Items` property is, but if that's the `ListBoxEdit`'s property, then it's pretty strange to be binding the object's `Items` property to its own `ItemsSource` property. There's plenty in the code you posted that is suggestive of "doing it wrong", but without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your problem, it's not really possible to offer specific advice.

Comment: @PeterDuniho added the essential code from my setup model, honestly it's entirely possibly that I am doing it wrong, that's why I posted here, for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the items with [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is example.
Very basic:

```
ICollectionView myCollectionVIew = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
myCollectionVIew.Filter = p => { return  p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SeachItems.ToLower();   };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bind the selected value. When you redraw, the value will be the same.

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Foreground="Black" Margin="10" 
                  Width="400" DisplayMember="Name" MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="200" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
                  EditValue="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}"
                  SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                  SelectedItem = {"Binding myNewVar"}>
```